# Show that $\tau_{x}: y \mapsto y-x, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n},$ is Borel measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Use Lemma 7.2 to show that $\tau_{x}: y \mapsto y-x, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n},$ is $\mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) / \mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ -measurable.

*Lemma 7.2* Let $(X, \mathscr{A}),\left(X^{\prime}, \mathscr{A}^{\prime}\right)$ be measurable spaces and let $\mathscr{A}^{\prime}=\sigma\left(\mathscr{G}^{\prime}\right) .$ Then
$T: X \rightarrow X^{\prime}$ is $\mathscr{A} / \mathscr{A}^{\prime}$ -measurable if, and only if $, T^{-1}\left(\mathscr{G}^{\prime}\right) \subset \mathscr{A},$ i.e. if
$$
T^{-1}\left(G^{\prime}\right) \in \mathscr{A} \quad \forall G^{\prime} \in \mathscr{G}^{\prime}
$$

---

I will like to use the fact that since $\tau_x$ is invertible, then the inverse image of some $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is the image of of $B$ under the inverse mapping $\tau_x^{-1} (y) = y+x$ (I'm not sure if the is the notation I should be using?)

I know that the family of open rectangles $$\mathscr{J}^{o}=\mathscr{J}^{o, n}=\mathscr{J}^{o}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)=\left\{\left(a_{1}, b_{1}\right) \times \cdots \times\left(a_{n}, b_{n}\right): a_{i}, b_{i} \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

is a generator of $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})^n$.

Take $J = \times_{i=1}^{n}\left(a_{i}, b_{i}\right)$,  then $\tau_x^{-1}(J)=J+x$. I will like to show that $J+x \in\mathscr{B}\mathbb{R}^n$. I actually do not know how to argue for that, since I'm not sure what $J+x$ is (means). I know that $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector, but I'm not sure what it means to add this to the set $J$. (**?**)

Comment: So the problem is that I do not know how to make since of the sum $J+x$ and that why this is still in $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Comment: A sum of measurable functions is measurable. Constant functions and the identity are measurable.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I end up with saying that $J+x$ is an translation of $J$. Since $J$ is in the Borel set, the $J+x$ must also be in the Borel set. Done, right?

Comment: Hint: $\tau_x$ is continuous, hence $\tau_x^{-1}[U]$ is open for any open set $U$. Now, use your lemma with open rectangles. Can you conclude?

Comment: @DominikKutek The conclusion will be that $\tau_{x}^{-1}[U] $ is also in the Borel set because of the continuity of $\tau_x$. I understand this. 

But how about my suggestion right above your comment ?

Comment: That's actually what you need to prove, since it's just a rephrasing of the original exercise.

Comment: Yes, just realised that. Thanks!

Comment: @Xenusi: For any open box $C=\prod^n_{j=1}(a_j,b_j)$, $\tau_x^{-1}(C)=x+C$ is also an open box. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra$\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$  is the minimum $\sigma$-algebra containing the open boxes. The collection $\mathcal{B}=\{B\subset\mathbb{R}^n:\tau_x^{-1}(B)\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and in contains that open boxes; thus $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz How is this different from what I wrote as a comment?

Comment: @OliverDiaz As I understand it. Vercassivelaunos means that it is not enough to say that  $x+C$ is in Borel set. One has to argue for it.

Comment: @Xenusi: I just outlined the general idea. One can substitute $\tau_x$ with any continuous function. Of course, $f^{-1}(C)$ is not a box in general, but it is enough to check that it is an open set. Invertibility of $f$ is not needed.

Comment: There is nothing to argue!, an open box is always open. It is the ball (in the $\|\;\|_1$ norm) centered at the some vector (figure this out yourself) wth some positive radius. All norms in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are equivalent (they generate the same topology). Let's not split hairs here.

Comment: Alright, I actually do not understand what you wrote in your first. Comment. Maybe it will make  sense later, because now I'm working on another problem, and it is hard for me to swift back and forward. Can not keep all that info in my head at the same time.